# Is Android encryption secure?

Tags: encryption, android, disk-encryption, phone, smartphone

As far as I know Android (Pie) is encrypted by default with some hardware-based password. But how secure is this encryption?

I am not talking about password compromise, but if somebody gets my phone, he just needs to turn it on to get data decrypted, so what’s the point? For what cases is this encryption designed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How secure is full-disk encryption technology on LineageOS, or Android phones in general?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/210994/how-secure-is-full-disk-encryption-technology-on-lineageos-or-android-phones-in)

Comment: Are you really asking "how secure is Android encryption when my phone doesn't have a password or PIN?" If that's what you're asking, then obviously it's not very secure, but that's nobody's fault but your own.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica maybe my wording is not the best. AFAIK encryption password is generated on hardware info only and your PIN/password is not really decrypting the info on your phone. That means, if somebody gets physical access to the phone and turns it on, data will be already decrypted. Without entering PIN/Password from your side (In case it is enabled). Correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: @FilipedosSantos hm, not really. Answer to the question you provided is answering on “how it works overall” (In general), but my question is more to “If data gets decrypted when phoned is turned on, why it’s still good to use it and how much PIN/Password saves your from case, when somebody get your phone and is able to turn it on (If it saves at all)?”

Comment: @Bukashka from where exactly are you quoting "“If data gets decrypted when phoned is turned on"?

Comment: @Bukashka have you read the answer to that question? I will quote here the relevant part: "the device encryption key is randomly generated and actually stored on the device. This encryption key is then itself encrypted using a mix of your supplied password/PIN/pattern and some device-specific hardware-backed information".

Comment: @Bukashka which basically means in order to use the device encryption key, whoever has the phone *must* know the device PIN/password. Have you read the official Android document regarding FDE? https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk

Comment: @FilipedosSantos my bad, got wrong answer you are referring to. So, encryption key is mixed with hardware info and PIN/Password of lockscreen and data gets decrypted after first PIN/Password input after device reboot?

Comment: @Bukashka I've wrote a more detailed answer, hope it clarifies :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am not talking about password compromise, but if somebody gets my
>   phone, he just needs to turn it on to get data decrypted, so what’s
>   the point? For what cases is this encryption designed?

I'm not sure from where you are quoting this statement, but it's false. Physical access to the device does *not* guarantee automatic decryption of the disk.

From the [official Android documentation](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk):

> Upon first boot, the device creates a randomly generated 128-bit
>   master key and then hashes it with a default password and stored salt.
>   The default password is: "default_password" However, the resultant
>   hash is also signed through a TEE (such as TrustZone), which uses a
>   hash of the signature to encrypt the master key.
>
> When the user sets the PIN/pass or password on the device, only the
>   128-bit key is re-encrypted and stored. (ie. user PIN/pass/pattern
>   changes do NOT cause re-encryption of userdata.) Note that managed
>   device may be subject to PIN, pattern, or password restrictions.

In the comments I've also referred to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/210994/how-secure-is-full-disk-encryption-technology-on-lineageos-or-android-phones-in) that answer a similar (if not equal) question.

Comment: So, after device reboot, on lockscreen (Before PIN/Password input) user data is still encrypted?

Comment: @Bukashka That's correct.

Comment: Does it mean, that after device restart you can't restore access with Google? `Since the encryption key is already decrypted while your device is powered on, it is easy for Android to just re-encrypt that key whenever it needs to, with a new password` [How secure is full-disk encryption technology on LineageOS, or Android phones in general?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/211035/224874). Because if an encryption key gets decrypted after PIN/Password input and only then it can be re-encrypted, restore can't be done after device reboot and before first password input?

Comment: The password/PIN _must_ be provided in order to decrypt the disk encryption key, that will then be used by the OS to decrypt the disk. Without providing the password/PIN, after reboot all the data is still encrypted.

Comment: But with Google you can restore access to your device (In order you forgot password), it's done by a re-encrypting the encryption key. But to re-encrypt key, it has to be decrypted. After reboot, before the first Password/PIN input encryption key is still encrypted, so Google can't restore access to your device?

Comment: No, unless you either provide the password/PIN, or set a new one via the password restore procedure established by Google (password restore link sent via email, phone call, SMS, etc).

Comment: So, if I set a new password I will get access to a device?

Comment: Yes, this is the entire purpose of a password and password reset mechanisms.

Comment: But how do a password reset mechanism can get access to encrypted data if an encryption key is encrypted by PIN/Password and I do not give it to it?

Comment: @Bukashka that's a good question, I came here for an answer and didn't find it.

Comment: As the answer is on full disc encryption only but this encryption technology is no longer used on devices since about Android 9 (the version the device is released with). As far as I know Google even enforces File Based Encryption on modern devices (since Android 10?).

Comment: Attack surface is bigger with File Based Encryption. For example, recent bug allowed to unlock/decrypt Pixel phones simply by replacing the SIM and entering the PUK code.  
https://bugs.xdavidhu.me/google/2022/11/10/accidental-70k-google-pixel-lock-screen-bypass/